# How to modify a character pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have been messing around with pointers and malloc for a little bit now, and when I tried to do this my compiler told me that there is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS for str[0] = 'a'. My goal in this simple program was to create a pointer that contains chars then start to make all of the letters lowercase. But it looks like I cannot even modify the content that the pointer is pointing to. Any and all help is much appreciated.

```
main(){

char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

if(str == NULL){
    printf("Error");
}

str = "AsDf";

str[0] = 'a';

printf("%s", str);

return 0;


}
```

Comment: This stuff is covered in any beginner C tutorial and has been asked a trillion times. Please do you research before asking questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
strncpy(str, 10, "AsDf");
```

instead of

```
str = "AsDf";
```

Comment: This is correct.  To explain further, originally you have `str` pointing at a 10 byte region of memory allocated by `malloc`.  When you do `str = "AsDf";` you are setting `str` to point at a different piece of memory, namely the string `"AsDf"`.  This string constant is likely placed into a read-only memory section.  So when you try to modify `str[0]`, you get the access error because you are trying to write to a read-only memory address.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "AsDf";
```

This line here assigns `str` to a string literal.  String literals are immutable; they cannot be changed.  You would have to initialize it like this to get your code to work:

```
str = {'A', 's', 'D', 'f', '\0'};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense. Been stuck on this forever.

Comment: @Tornadoe1123 ensc's answer is much more correct than mine, i would suggest accepting his answer!